# base64 encode string from a terminal?

Tags: c++, macos, encoding, command-line, base64

OS X 10.8.3
C++

We have base64 encode and decode functions in our code.

However, I want to base64 encode a string from my terminal and use it in my code so our functions can decode it when it needs to be used.

How does one base64 encode a string from a terminal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the `base64` command, sensibly enough:

```
# echo -n Hello | base64
SGVsbG8K
# echo SGVsbG8K | base64 -D
Hello
```

Comment: You probably want to supply the `-n` option to `echo` so that it doesn't emit the trailing newline.

Comment: @duskwuff - Thanks. I was under the impression I had to use OpenSSL, this was way to simple. Borderline not using my head.

Comment: Works on 10.8.3, Is there anyway to get this on a 10.6 machine too? I dont think it comes on 10.6. I bet there is a package someplace

Comment: @Jason: `openssl base64` and `openssl base64 -d` are your best bet on earlier releases.

Comment: @devnull: Omitting `-n` in my example was intentional to make the decoded output display cleanly. And yes, it's really `-D` on this version; `-d` enables a debugging mode.

Comment: @duskwuff Suggests that `base64` on Mac isn't provided by GNU coreutils.

Comment: @devnull: Correct. OS X is more closely related to BSD, so it uses BSD-derived utilities, not GNU.

Comment: The issue with openssl base64 is that the line length is not configurable as in base64

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://superuser.com/questions/120796/how-to-encode-base64-via-command-line#:%7E:text=base64%20command%20is%20available%20by,encode%20and%20decode%20a%20file.&text=%2Dn%20is%20to%20avoid%20a,the%20end%20of%20the%20line.):

base64 command is available by default on my OS X 10.9.4.

**Encoding:** `base64 <<< string`. 
**Decoding:** `base64 -D <<< string`.