# Converting hexidecimal color value to base64 for .terminal file

Tags: macos, encoding, terminal, base64, plist

I understand that `.terminal` files use base64 encoding to go from (what looks like) sRGB to a data value that the default Mac Terminal app can interpret.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675459/base64-encode-string-from-a-terminal), I can decode base64 text into text that is somewhat more understandable using something like

```
echo IzEyMzQ1Ngo= | base64 --decode
# returns #123456
```

However, when converting existing `.terminal` data values using the above method I am left with text that looks like

```
UNSRGB\NSColorSpaceV$classO*0.08235294118 0.08235294118 0.08235294118��Z$classnameX$classesWNSColor�XNSObject_NSKeyedArchiver�Troot#-27;AHN[b
```

How can I go from a hex color value (ex: #123456) to the base64 value that is needed for a `.terminal` file for a color preference (the ANSI color preferences) using the command line?

Comment: That looks like something from a _binary property list_, which contains more than just the RGB values - the kind of object, colorspace, etc.  You might want to check out https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98655/how-are-colorschemes-represented-in-os-x-terminal-app-settings-files

Comment: @red_menace that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!